# ios : Are there any mature libraries out there for drag \ drop \ rotate functionality - similar to dragkit

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I am new to ios development.
I am looking for a mature open source library that will offer some drag & drop \ Rotation and zoom functionality. Are there any such libraries out there?

I found Dragkit, but it seems like somebody's side project. Do you know if there are any maturer alternatives?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at Oblong we created a self-contained iOS drag and drop library that can work across arbitrary views:

https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop

It is more focused towards dropping items from one view to another and as such it doesn't have zoom or rotation handling, but that is a functionality that could be added in the future.